# Google App Engine user authentication

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I make people signup using email(not gmail) and login with their emails?
Snapchat, Khan academy and songpop all use google app engine but not gmail as login.
I use google app engine sdk for python. What should I do and where can I find info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine authentication options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181648/google-app-engine-authentication-options)

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a built-in User Service for convenience only. You can use any form of authentication on App Engine: your own, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

If you are new to authentication, the best option is to use a package that does all the work for you, like [Django Social Auth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth) or [Python Social Auth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-social-auth/).